# Get current user array into hyperlink

Tags: users, array

I am unsure how to take data from the user array and place some of these values into the following hyperlink. I want to replace the email address, first name and last name with the values from the currently logged in user array.

```
<a href="https://thinkmcat.webex.com/thinkmcat/m.php?AT=EN&AE=testreg@testdomain.com&FN=Firstname&LN=Lastname&&MK=665080128&PW=miami&BU=http://thinkmcat.com/">

<?php
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
/**
 * @example Safe usage: $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
 * if ( !($current_user instanceof WP_User) )
 *     return;
 */
echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . '<br />';
echo 'User email: ' . $current_user->user_email . '<br />';
echo 'User first name: ' . $current_user->user_firstname . '<br />';
echo 'User last name: ' . $current_user->user_lastname . '<br />';
echo 'User display name: ' . $current_user->display_name . '<br />';
echo 'User ID: ' . $current_user->ID . '<br />';

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would set up an array with the variables you want in the url query string and then use [http_build_query()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php).

Like so:

```
$args = array( 'AT' => 'EN',
               'AE' => $current_user->user_email,
               'FN' => $current_user->user_firstname,
               'LN' => $current_user->user_lastname,
               'MK' => 665080128,
               'PW' => 'miami',
               'BU' => 'http://thinkmcat.com/');

?>

<a href="https://thinkmcat.webex.com/thinkmcat/m.php?<?php echo http_build_query($args); ?>">LINK</a>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I wish there was some way I could repay you. If you ever need something SEO related, I consult large SEO agencies as an experts' expert.